# How to make the application wait untill the download is finished

Tags: android, api, progress-bar, android-room, android-download-manager

Hey Android developers.

Can anyone tell me how to fetch data which is around 8-10 Mb from API and save it in the room database?

The app should wait and show a progress bar screen until the download is complete and if a network error occurs which result in an unfinished download it should resume when the app restarts.

I am familiar with fetching data from API and saving it to the room database.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question is very general. You say you are already familiar with fetching data and saving to a room database. So what exactly are you having problems with? Please edit your question and post some code and/or explain your exact issue.

Comment: While the data is getting downloaded from api and is being saved to the local db i want to hold that screen and show a progress dailog.

Comment: Search for "android download progress bar". There are numerous ways to do this. Look at examples using `AsyncTask`, but there are also other alternatives.